# Get the URL, width and height of an image where the width and height are a specified minimum

Tags: images

Is it possible to get the URL, height and width of an image where the height and width are as a minimum the size I specify?

`wp_get_attachment_image_src()` almost does this, but not quite, grabbing instead the image where either one of the height or width is as a minimum the size I specify.

## Example

For example this -> `wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_the_ID(), array(208,208));` will return these results -

```
array (
  0 => 'http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/image-name-300x168.jpg',
  1 => 208,
  2 => 116,
  3 => true,
)
```

As you can see, the height is less than 208, so when I display the image using those attributes it becomes stretched.

so in the case of the above I would actually require WP to find the next size image and return these results -

```
array (
  0 => 'http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/image-name-672x372.jpg',
  1 => 376,
  2 => 208,
  3 => true,
)
```

Naturally I don't just want to grab the original (thus largest) image as that will unnecessarily eat bandwidth and cause the page load to be slower.

## Background

In case you are wondering why I require this, I am displaying 4x images in a row in a square container (208x208). The images are both horizontally and vertically centered, and I need the images to fill the container while being as small as possible.

## Code

```
<?php
if($this->items->have_posts()) : while($this->items->have_posts()) : $this->items->the_post();

        $last = ($this->is_last_on_line()) ? 'last' : false;
        $media_preview = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_the_ID(), array(208,208));
        $sizing = ($media_preview[1] >= $media_preview[2]) ? 'height="208"' : 'width="208"';                
?>
        <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="preview-container <?php echo $last; ?>">   
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
                <img src="<?php echo $media_preview[0]; ?>" <?php echo $sizing; ?> />
            </a>
        </div>
<?php
    endwhile;
endif;
wp_reset_query();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the size of the square container before hand as you do, 208x208px then why not just add a custom image size to your functions file and call that image size in your template.

Add this to your themes functions.php:

```
add_image_size( 'custom-size', 208, 208, true );
```

if you are running WordPress 3.9 you can use cropping as well so you could use it like this:

```
add_image_size( 'custom-size', 220, 220, array( 'center', 'center' ) );
```

Then call it in your template file:

```
$media_preview = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID, 'custom-size') );
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've already done just what you suggested for the `add_image_size()` in relation to cropping, which is fine going forward. However this unfortunately no good for images that had already been added before that size existed.

Comment: Not to worry, use this plugin by Viper007bond,Regenerate Thumbnails . I use it all the time, its an absolute life saver! http://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/